# What is the actual structure of Hive Partitioned /bucketed table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

Im not able to configure multi data node cluster in virtual box

Do not consider the replicating factor take it as 1.

Say i have a 10GB file and have a column city which have 2 distinct values and i have 2 Data nodes.

Want to partition the data by City.
Also i will bucket postcode in 2 buckets in each partition .
My question is Will each partition be present in every Data node or each Node will have only distinct partition.

My understanding is that each node will have all the partitions but in some node the partitions may not be present because of not enough values in Data file.
Each partition in each Data Node will be bucketed by Postcodes and again some bucket may not have value .

Comment: HDFS will hold a directory for each partition. As far as actual raw datanode data, I guess it would make sense to keep the partitions data local to one node

Comment: This is confusing me . If what u r guessing is true then Partition in HIVE is equivalent to say Primary Index of Teradata or i say a mechanism to data distribution like MPP systems. But the question comes if say i have a 100 node cluster  and i divide my file in 30 partitions then only 30 nodes will be used ( leaving aside replication). i m confused. Also then How non partitioned Bucketing table works. Is it also Bucket per node. ?

Comment: I usually don't look at the raw datanode data, so I'm only speculating about map reduce operations over the partition key. If you have a 100 node cluster, the replica count better be more than 1

Comment: just stating abt replica count 1 so that my actual question does not get diverted. BTW i found one blog in which it says Hive  for bucketing will show one logical file  but actually it stores data across nodes . I guess it is similar in case of partitions. This is one of the major diff between prop MPP and Hadoop/Hive MPP.

Comment: Impala is an MPP. Hive is not prior to Hive LLAP

Comment: There is thin line between general purpose distributed parallel processing framework and traditional MPP. But i do not want to divert the focus from my question.

Comment: Alright, well it shouldn't take too long to get a Hortonworks sandbox up and running if you would like to test out your hypothesis.

Comment: sorry . i was busy.  i will download sandbox.  will it be possible to create 2  data nodes and one namenode  easily as my comp is only dual core. in oracle vm if i try to increase the processor more than 2 .

Comment: There's only one datanode in the sandbox, as it is only computer. If you need a "distributed cluster" on your PC, I think Cloudera has something called "clusterdock" that uses Docker

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning is implemented using directories.
A directory contains files. Might be one, might be many.

Bucketing is implemented using files.
A bucket may be related to one file or to many files.

Files are built from blocks. Might be one, might be many.
A block reside within a node. Different blocks might reside on the same node or on different nodes.

bottom line -
There is nothing that ties a partition/bucket to a specific node.

Comment: Thanks a lot .  Appreciate.

Comment: You're welcome. Please note the change in the answer regarding bucketing (sorry, it was late... :-)) - but the bottom line remains the same.

Comment: i apologize . I respect you .  i was little bit under influence . sorry.. The question that i had put in earlier it was bugging me for long time . my doubt will linger on . Apologies again .